# Error: Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: php, symfony, controller

I am trying to send mail with Swift_Message however when I go to send the data it will not send and I get an error of

> FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function get() on a
>   non-object in
>   /vagrant/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php
>   line 252

Here is the Email Controller that I am using.

```
use Symfony\Component\Finder\Shell\Command;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class EmailController extends Controller{

    public function createMessage($subject, $from, $from_name, $to, $to_name, $body){
        // Create the message
        $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()

            // Give the message a subject
            ->setSubject($subject)

            // Set the From address with an associative array
            ->setFrom(array($from => $from_name))

            // Set the To addresses with an associative array
            ->setTo(array($to => $to_name))

            // Give it a body
            ->setBody($body, 'text/html');

        return $message;
    }

    public function sendEmail($message, $urlAlias){

        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($urlAlias));
    }
}
```

I understand that its unable to access the object which I think is part of the container class but I can seem to get it to pull up.  I have tried using `$this->container->get(...`

but that also does not work.  What am I missing.  This seems like it should be really straight forward.

I am calling this function from a different bundle using an action to call the current controller.  I don't know if that makes a difference.

---

Ok so when looking in /vagrant/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php

The line it errors on is

```
   /**
     * Gets a service by id.
     *
     * @param string $id The service id
     *
     * @return object The service
     */
    public function get($id)
    {
        return $this->container->get($id);
    }
}
```

Which makes me feel like 'mailer; is not a good $id but it is used in Symfony's examples and in a lot of other private examples.

Don't know if this helps or not but figured it was worth mentioning.

Could this be because of the swiftmailer: setting inside of my config.yml file?

routing.yml file

```
fuel_form_homepage:
    pattern:  /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: FuelFormBundle:Default:index }

referral_form:
    pattern:   /form/referral/{hash}
    defaults: { _controller: FuelFormBundle:Form:referralForm }

referral_result:
    pattern:  /form/referral/result
    defaults: { _controller: FuelFormBundle:Form:referralResult }

user_form:
    pattern:    /form/user
    defaults: { _controller: FuelFormBundle:Form:userForm }

home:
    pattern:    /
    defaults: { _controller: FuelFormBundle:Default:home}
```

---

This is the function that calls

```
public function userFormAction(request $request){
        $user = new User();
        $form = $this->createForm('user', $user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if($form->isValid()){
            $user->setTimeCreated();
            $user->setTimeUpdated();
            $date = $user->getTimeCreated();
            $timestamp = $date->format("U");
            $hash = $user->getFirstName() . $user->getLastName() . $timestamp ;
            $user->setUserHash(md5($hash));
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            print_r($user);
            //TODO: @Email: @Body: make sure to replace with correct information.

            //Calls a service named email_bundle_controller
            $emailController = $this->get('email_bundle_controller');

            $fullName = $user->getFirstName() . $user->getLastName();
            $body = "please visit the following url to start referring! <a href='http://localhost:8080/app_dev.php/form/referral/" . $user->getUserHash() . "'>Your URL</a>";
            $message = $emailController->createMessage('Welcome to Fuel PRM References', 'bsaverino@gmail.com', 'Brad Saverino', $user->getEmail(), $fullName, $body);
            $emailController->sendEmail($message, 'user_form');

        }

        return $this->render('FuelFormBundle:Default:mainForm.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView(),));

    }
```

This is the service that allows me to call on the other bundle.

```
services:
    fuel_form.form.type.referral:
        class: Fuel\FormBundle\Form\Type\ReferralType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: referral}

    fuel_form.form.type.user:
        class: Fuel\FormBundle\Form\Type\UserType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: user}

    email_bundle_controller:
        class: Fuel\EmailBundle\Controller\EmailController
```

---

This is the FuelEmailBundle.php

```
namespace Fuel\EmailBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class FuelEmailBundle extends Bundle
{
    private static $containerInstance = null;

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        parent::setContainer($container);
        self::$containerInstance = $container;
    }

    public static function getContainer()
    {
        return self::$containerInstance;
    }
}
```

These are the changes that were made to the sendEmail function

```
public function sendEmail($message, $urlAlias){

        $container = FuelEmailBundle::getContainer();

        $mailer = $container->get('mailer');

        $mailer->send($message);

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl($urlAlias));
    }
```

Comment: I can get this to work without error if I put everything within the same controller.

Comment: Can you post your route definitions?

Comment: Is that the routing.yml file? Just added it.

Comment: Ok, so when `sendMail` gets called, is it from an event hook or are you actually generating a request to that controller?

Comment: The error is because the container is not being set.  You are trying to new your email controller which is why the container is not being set.  Post some code showing how createMessage is being called.

Comment: I just posted the call to createMessage and the service being used to call the other bundle.  Thank you for taking a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Cerad had mentioned above, you are getting the error as container is not set. One way of fixing this issue would be to pass a container instance to your bundle so that you can call the container from anywhere in your project.

Edit the class corresponding to your bundle(BundleName.php) to include two methods setContainer and getContainer. See the example below.

```
namespace Venom\CoreBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use \Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class VenomCoreBundle extends Bundle
{
   private static $containerInstance = null; 

   public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null) 
   { 
    parent::setContainer($container); 
    self::$containerInstance = $container; 
   }

   public static function getContainer() 
   { 
    return self::$containerInstance; 
   }
 }
```

Use the appropriate namespaces.
Then, use the namespace for the bundle in classes where you need the container. 
You may call the container by

`$container = VenomCoreBundle::getContainer();`

Then, call the mailer

`$mailer = $container->get('mailer');`

Comment: This doesn't work.  I am still getting the same error.  I entered the above code into my php bundle.  I include it into my bundle I set the $container and use it and I still get the same error.  I can get it to work when everything is in the same bundle and controller but as soon as I move them to separate bundles they don't work.  Do I need to do this in the bundle that is calling the function, not in the actual function it self.  I am not sure how I would accomplish this.

Comment: However if I use `$container = FuelFormBundle::getContainer();` and call the function like this `$container->sendEmail($message, 'user_form');` then I get an error FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method appDevDebugProjectContainer::sendEmail() in /vagrant/src/Fuel/FormBundle/Controller/FormController.php line 76.  Which makes sense because now it has no way to locate the function.  I am missing something.

Comment: For others googling this issue, if you're trying to do subrequests within a controller via $this->forward( '..newcontroller' ), I found the container isn't passed to the subcontrollers. Using Praveesh's solution above works around the issue, which I'd consider a bug in symfony.

Comment: @BRad how did you fix it eventually?